# Sorting a column with numbers, strings and nils

Tags: mysql

I have a column that includes numbers (as strings), strings and nils.
I would like to order all numbers by numerical values, then strings alphabetically, then all nils and empty strings sorted through another column.

so, given:

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | val | name |
+----+-----+------+
| 0  |bbb  |      |
| 1  |aaa  |      |
| 2  |0920 |      |
| 3  |320  |      |
| 4  |     |c     |
| 5  |NULL |b     |
| 6  |     |a     |
+----+-----+------+
```

I want:

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | val | name |
+----+-----+------+
| 3  |320  |      |
| 2  |0920 |      |
| 1  |aaa  |      |
| 0  |bbb  |      |
| 6  |     |a     |
| 5  |NULL |b     |
| 4  |     |c     |
+----+-----+------+
```

thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6246fc/5)**

First use a `CASE` to create groups, numbers go first, null go last, the rest in on the middle

Then sort by the numeric value, and the name

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `val` REGEXP '[0-9]+' THEN 1 
              WHEN `val` IS NULL THEN 3
              ELSE 2
         END,
         CASE WHEN `val` REGEXP '[0-9]+' THEN CONVERT(`val`, SIGNED INTEGER)
              ELSE 0
         END,
         name
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id |    val |   name |
|----|--------|--------|
|  3 |    320 | (null) |
|  2 |   0920 | (null) |
|  0 |    bbb | (null) |
|  1 |    aaa | (null) |
|  6 | (null) |      a |
|  5 | (null) |      b |
|  4 | (null) |      c |
```